# How to set up multiple app users in Android for Firebase Crashlytics, including compliance GDPR?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am working with Firebase for the first time and new with the concept. I am trying to set up the Firebase Crashlytics for multiple app users. 
My app generates for every handheld specific id that is used for multiple purposes.

**Question:**

1. How to implement the handheld id to the Firebase Crashlytics in my app?

*Reason:*

When using  Firebase Console, I would like to see the handheld id and base on that I know who has some problem with the app.

**Question:**

2. How to set the Firebase Crashlytics in my app, so when my app crash, the log will be stored locally?

*Reason:*

When handheld does not have an internet connection and my app crash, I would like to be able to analyse the log or resend the log to the Firebase Console.

**Question:**

3. How to use the Firebase Crashlytics, so the app compliance GDPR?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

1. Crashlytics support custom logging, which will let you [associate a crash report with a particular ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports-new-sdk?platform=android#set-user-ids).
2. Crashlytics will always store crashes locally and attempt to send them up next time the app relaunches. If it's unable to send them up it will cache them and continue trying when there is a better network connection. If you're controlling Crashlytics data collection manually via setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled, you can use methods like [sendUnsentReports()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasecrashlytics/api/reference/Classes/Crashlytics#sendunsentreports) and [deleteUnsentReports()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasecrashlytics/api/reference/Classes/Crashlytics#deleteunsentreports) to control the behavior.
3. Check out [Firebase's privacy and security page](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy) for more information about GDPR compliance. For Crashlytics, you can log unique user IDs to associate users with each crash session sent to your Crashlytics dashboard, and then you can send Firebase support a GDPR data deletion request with the associated ID to make sure you're wiping out your data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to rename the activity name in Firebase -> Console -> Performance that already exists? 
Later on, I find out that I can set the name by 
mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(SplashScreen.this, "SS", "SS");

Comment: Thos eactivity names can't be renamed in Firebase Performance.